# Auto-increment on partial primary key with Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have declared the following model using the EF Core fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
    .HasKey(p => new { p.Name, p.Id });
```

Both fields are marked as the primary key when I create the database in PostgreSQL but the Id field is not marked as auto increment. I have also tried to add

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

to the Id field under Foo without it making any difference on the migration code. Is there a way to make the Id AI although it is a PPK?

Comment: What type is your `Id` property?

Comment: Id is int, Name is a string

Comment: If `Id` is an auto-generated number why do you need to have `Name` as part of the primary key as well?

Comment: If anyone thinks that this question needs more answers: the issue here is that an existing key column can't be changed into an identity column just like that. See answers and comments below (as you always should before posting new stuff).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Well those Data Annotations should do the trick, maybe is something related with the PostgreSQL Provider.

From [EF Core documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties):

> Depending on the database provider being used, values may be generated
>   client side by EF or in the database. If the value is generated by the
>   database, then EF may assign a temporary value when you add the entity
>   to the context. This temporary value will then be replaced by the
>   database generated value during `SaveChanges`.

You could also try with this Fluent Api configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .Property(f => f.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

But as I said earlier, I think this is something related with the DB provider. Try to add a new row to your DB and check later if was generated a value to the `Id` column.

Comment: I've marked this as an answer despite that I haven't gotten my code fully working. This throws an exception on startup saying "Not supporting creating IsIdentity for int4" so I guess you are right and that this depends on the DB provider and so far it doesn't seem like they have implemented support for it yet.

Comment: Just a follow up, with PostgreSQL you cannot modify an existing field to become AI. This resulted in the exception I got previously so I have to throw away my db, create a new one and put in all the data.

Answer (score 37):

First of all you should not merge the Fluent Api with the data annotation so I would suggest you to use one of the below:

make sure you have correclty set the keys

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
            .HasKey(p => new { p.Name, p.Id });
modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

**OR** you can achieve it using data annotation as well

```
public class Foo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not when he's defining it in fluent api, the order is the order of the properties in the anonymous object

Comment: HasDatabaseGeneratedOption doesn't appear to exist in the version I am using (7.0.0-rc1-final), or am I missing an extension or something?

Comment: I don't think this solve the OP's issue. He is merging Fluent Api (where he establishes the Ids order) with Data Annotations (where he specifies that `Id` property is Identity). I personally don't like to merge those two features, but his configuration should work. I think what is happening depends more of DB provider.

Comment: @octavioccl I agree in fact I suggested 2 different options one using data annotation and another one using Fluent API.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso But that isn't the issue, that part is right in the code from the OP in the first place

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I think that mixing the two "style" may call the issue because fluent configuration overrides DataAnnotations

Comment: Im trying to stick with the fluent API, but as far as I see, HasDatabaseGeneratedOption is only present in EF6 and not EF7. Or is there an extension I need to use to get access to that feature?

Comment: Data annotations *do not work* with EF Core: `Entity type 'Blah' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.`

Answer (score 21):

To anyone who came across this question who are using **SQL Server Database** and still having an exception thrown even after adding the following annotation on the int primary key

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Please check your SQL, make sure your the primary key has 'IDENTITY(startValue, increment)' next to it,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User]
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
)
```

This will make the database increments the id every time a new row is added, with a starting value of 1 and increments of 1.

I accidentally overlooked that in my SQL which cost me an hour of my life,
so hopefully this helps someone!!!

Comment: Still i am facing error "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'User' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."

Comment: Im getting the same error, I have primary key of Id and Version, on updates I want to add new entries by incrementing my version but keeping the Id, havent found a good solution yet.

Answer (score 14):

Annotate the property like below

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

To use identity columns for all value-generated properties on a new model, simply place the following in your context's **OnModelCreating():**

```
builder.ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns();
```

This will create make all keys and other properties which have .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() have Identity by default. You can use ForNpgsqlUseIdentityAlwaysColumns() to have Identity always, and you can also specify identity on a property-by-property basis with UseNpgsqlIdentityColumn() and UseNpgsqlIdentityAlwaysColumn().

[postgres efcore value generation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/value-generation.html)

Comment: under latest version of.netcore EF, ForNpgsqlUseIdentityColumns is deprecated, use the following line builder.UseIdentityColumns

Answer (score 2):

> Specifying the column type as serial for PostgreSQL to generate the id.

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
[Column(Order=1, TypeName="serial")]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Comment: Setting TypeName="serial" it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

To use a map id, autoincrement, using FluentAPI

```
namespace DEPLOY.Cachorro.Infra.Repository.EntityConfigurations
{
    internal class TutorEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tutor>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Tutor> builder)
        {
            builder
                .ToTable("Tutor");   

            builder
                .Property(x => x.Id)
                .UseIdentityColumn(seed: 1,increment: 1)
                .HasColumnName("Id")
                .HasColumnType("int")
                .IsRequired();
```

for more details:

> https://github.com/felipementel/DEPLOY.Cachorro.Api/blob/main/src/DEPLOY.Cachorro.Repository/EntityConfigurations/TutorEntityConfiguration.cs

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Now i write a really useful explanation with example

Comment: You didn't understand the real issue, see my comment above. `UseIdentityColumn` is nothing but the fluent equivalent of the attribute in OP's code.