# Identity increment for char c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, auto-increment

As i find this problem, i can't found any same problem in the internet especially in this website.

I really know, integer data type is really different from char data type. 
When i use integer for id, this id can increment automatically from the settings below the tables-> [Link for description](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2a3yLvf0rMKcDUwVkhreFY5d0k). In other hand, when i use char data type it can't do it. -> [link for description](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2a3yLvf0rMKbG5LRTBhXzY2bVk).

Besides of the increment problem (the reason why i MUST use this char), the data must contain 2 character and 3 number (for example: LA002) but the id must be generated automatically and rises gradually for the number example LA001, LA002, LA..., LAnnn.

Any answer of codes or how i can set them automatically, may help me to solve this problem. Thanks before for your help.

Comment: I think you can use a `composite key` which is a combination of an `auto-increment id` and a string (in your case: LA)

Comment: You have posted two images about a DB, but you aren't including any sql tag. You aren't even specifying if this autoincrement should be done SQL-side or c# side.

Comment: @kienct89 do i must do a code for the "composite key" problem while is it must an auto complete syntax?

Comment: @xanatos: i'm sorry for that.. but as i know, this problem should be completed by c#.. thanks for the suggestion..

Comment: since you didn't mention any technical details in your question, I'm going to assume you're using EF Core with MSSQL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155429/auto-increment-on-partial-primary-key-with-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @kienct89: thanks for it.. i'll read it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom primary key combined with an auto-increment identity column:

```
CREATE TABLE AutoIncrementCustomIDTable
(
    MyKey AS ('LA' + LEFT('000', 3 - LEN(AutoIncId)) + CONVERT(varchar(3), AutoIncId)) PERSISTED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    
    AutoIncId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Col1 VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO AutoIncrementCustomIDTable (Col1) VALUES ('111')
INSERT INTO AutoIncrementCustomIDTable (Col1) VALUES ('222')
INSERT INTO AutoIncrementCustomIDTable (Col1) VALUES ('333')

SELECT * FROM AutoIncrementCustomIDTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two columns 
one column contains default 'LA' prefix and second COLUMN for autoincremental id, both of which are grouped for the primary key.

> CREATE TABLE(
>       id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>       prefix CHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'LA',
>       PRIMARY KEY (id, prefix))