# How to save custom value in ID column using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I am using code first approach, I don't know how to pass custom id into ID column Whenever I try to pass id its show the following error:

> Can't insert null to table Orders.ID Insert fails

```
public class Order 
{       
    [Key]
    public int  ID { get; set; } // I WANT THIS COLUMN SHOULD BE SAVED AS "10001,10002,10003" INSTEAD OF "1,2,3,4"
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerEmail { get; set; }

    public virtual List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
    
    public virtual List<OrderHistory> OrderHistory { get; set; }
}

public class OrderHistory 
{
   
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
}

public class OrderItem 
{        
    public int OrderID { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
  
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Item Price is in Order Item because we can have a scenerio where we might charge less or greater than the Product Price.
    /// </summary>
    public decimal ItemPrice { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT-2**

After adding on ID its now throwing another error as
Invalid column name 'ID'
Invalid column name 'ID'

```
 [Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public int ID { get; set; }
```

Comment: Looks like you might have autoincrement in your DB set on ID: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: Here is the answer of your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55269266/using-entity-framework-with-code-first-no-autoincrement

Comment: @PawZaw Hello, Thanks for quick replay, but Id is not set in auto increment and the column identity specification is  No

Comment: If you don't specify anything, EF will auto-map the column as identity column. Looks like you only have to increase the seed value of the identity specification.

Comment: From migration seems it wont work. I have work around using this command while you add migration command, before that you caould add this like.  `migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Order ', RESEED, 10001)");` Though you could add expected sequence for non primary key column but so far I have tested it does't work for `primary key column` because migration always add `.Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)` this commands. Hopefully you got my points.

Comment: does [this](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/faq/how-to-set-explicit-value-to-id-property-in-ef-core.aspx) solve your problem ?

Comment: @GordonKhanhNg. I think `migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Order ', RESEED, 1001)");` this script would be more easider for him scenario.

Comment: Hello, is there anything else that I can assist on this?

Comment: No Thanks @MdFaridUddinKiron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your scenario you could implement like below ways. I have work around using this command while you `add migration command`, before that you could add this like below

```
 migrationBuilder.Sql("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Order ', RESEED, 10001)");
```

Though you could add expected sequence for non primary key column but so far I have tested it does't work for primary key column because migration always add this commands. Which enforced `SQL server to take the controls of identity`

```
.Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
```

> ***Note:*** So we need to add above mensioned command to override it. Which implement the custom identity as we want.

Hope it will help you to acheive your goal.