# How to restart postgres sequence with Entity framework seeding migration?

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, seeding, .net-core-3.1

I have the following database seeder:

```
public partial class Seed_Languages : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.InsertData(
                table: "Languages",
                columns: new[] { "LanguageId", "LangCode", "LangName", "Sort" },
                values: new object[,]
                {
                    { 1, "AU", "Австралия", 0 },
                    { 159, "CX", "Остров Рождества", 0 },
                    { 160, "PN", "Острова Питкэрн", 0 },
                    { 161, "SH", "Острова Святой Елены, Вознесения и Тристан-да-Кунья", 0 },
                    { 162, "PK", "Пакистан", 0 },
                    { 163, "PW", "Палау", 0 },

.... and so on ...
```

As you can see I'm going to populate some table, that contains language's names (on Russian, for showing on UI), language's codes, some additional field - `Sort` (not important here) and primary key. Simple, right? 
Here is the table:

[image]

Then I create it inside my `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

   // many fluent api calls 
   LanguagesSeeder.SeedLanguages(modelBuilder);
}
```

Then I run `$ dotnet ef database update` and seeding works fine! But problems soon began.

When I try to insert new one language, .NET gives me:

> Exception data:
>       Severity: ERROR
>       SqlState: 23505
>       MessageText: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Languages"
>       Detail: Key ("LanguageId")=(1) already exists.
>       SchemaName: public
>       TableName: Languages
>       ConstraintName: PK_Languages
>       File: nbtinsert.c
>       Line: 434

"Hmmmm lets try again" - I thought. And:

> Exception data:
>       Severity: ERROR
>       SqlState: 23505
>       MessageText: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "PK_Languages"
>       Detail: Key ("LanguageId")=(2) already exists.
>       SchemaName: public
>       TableName: Languages
>       ConstraintName: PK_Languages
>       File: nbtinsert.c
>       Line: 434
>       Routine: _bt_check_unique

You see that? The same error but with another Primary key complaint! The first was: `Key ("LanguageId")=(1) already exists.` and the second `Key ("LanguageId")=(2) already exists.`
!

So, what to do? I know this way:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE <name of sequence> RESTART WITH <your number is here>;
```

But it's pretty uncomfortable to run this SQL in a console after seeding. Am I miss something? Maybe, there is a standard way for this, I mean using some EF API?

#### Update

I will show you my `Language` model:

```
namespace Domains
{
    public class Language
    {
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }

        public int Sort { get; set; }

        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }        

        public List<PushMessageLang> PushMessageLangs { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public IEnumerable<PushMessage> PushMessages
        {
            get => PushMessageLangs?.Select(r => r.PushMessage);
            set => PushMessageLangs = value.Select(v => new PushMessageLang()
            {
                PushMessageId = v.PushMessageId
            }).ToList();
        }

        public string LangName { get; set; }

        public string LangCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I make insert via my repository abstraction:

Base repository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T, C> : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where C : DbContext
{
    protected C DataContext;
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbset;

    public BaseRepository(C context)
    {
        DataContext = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> All => _dbset;

    public virtual async Task SaveAsync(T entity)
    {
        await _dbset.AddAsync(entity);
        await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public async Task SaveAsync(List<T> entity)
    {
        await _dbset.AddRangeAsync(entity);
        await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Attach(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _dbset.Update(entity);
        await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(int id)
    {
        var dbEntity =  await _dbset.FindAsync(id);

        if (dbEntity != null)
        {
            _dbset.Remove(dbEntity);
            await DataContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

And in the controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromForm] LanguageViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    var newLanguage = new Language()
    {
        Sort = viewModel.Sort,
        LangCode = viewModel.Code,
        LangName = viewModel.Name
    };

    await _languageRepository.SaveAsync(newLanguage);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

#### Update 2

As asked in the comments I'll pin here all fluent api for `Language` model:

```
// many to many with `Message` entity
modelBuilder.Entity<PushMessageLang>()
    .HasKey(bc => new { bc.PushLangId, bc.PushMessageId });

modelBuilder.Entity<PushMessageLang>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.Language)
    .WithMany(b => b.PushMessageLangs)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PushLangId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<PushMessageLang>()
    .HasOne(bc => bc.PushMessage)
    .WithMany(c => c.PushMessageLangs)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.PushMessageId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

// has unique language code
modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
    .HasIndex(x => x.LangCode).IsUnique();
```

#### Update 3

As asked @Roman Marusyk, I pine here SQL script for creating `Languages` table.

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table "Languages"
(
    "LanguageId" integer generated by default as identity
        constraint "PK_Languages"
            primary key,
    "LangName"   text,
    "LangCode"   text,
    "Sort"       integer default 0 not null
);

alter table "Languages"
    owner to makeapp_pushes;

create unique index "IX_Languages_LangCode"
    on "Languages" ("LangCode");
```

Hmm, now I see that don't have anything about auto increment.
But my SQL client shows my:

[image]

Comment: Show us your `Language` model and how you make an insert. The `LanguageId` should have `SERIAL` type in database to automatically increment the value. Or you should do it manually in the code

Comment: @RomanMarusyk done! Could you check?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk DataGrip (my database client) texts me that LanguageId is integer. But it also has `autoincrement` label. And if I try to insert into a table that was created by similar way (but without seeding) I can insert with auto increment. Without any PK errors.

Comment: Where is your model configuration?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk fluent api?

Comment: yes, fluent api for Language

Comment: @RomanMarusyk done! Not so many. Just on many-to-many relation (one Message with Language) and  unique constraint.

Answer (score 2):

Add [`HasKey`](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/haskey-method) to model configuration

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
    .HasKey(x => x.LanguageId)
    .HasIndex(x => x.LangCode).IsUnique();
```

as @IvanStoev mentioned, by convention, the property `LanguageId` is already the primary key

Try to specify

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
        .Property(p => p.LanguageId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try it as soon as I can! And I will report here about the result. Ok?

Comment: This won't make any difference - property called `LanguageId` in class called `Language` is already the primary key [by convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I have tried it. Thank you for help, but it does not work. If I add `  modelBuilder.Entity<Language>()
        .Property(p => p.LanguageId)
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();` and make new one migration - the migration is empty.  It not effects on database. When I try to insert new one `Language` I have the same error.

Comment: Try to drop table - specify `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` - create a new migration and run. See https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/73

Comment: @RomanMarusyk no. I have tried it, The same problem. I have the same SQL without serial or something about auto increment :(

Comment: Did you try `.Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", "SERIAL")`?. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155429/auto-increment-on-partial-primary-key-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: @RomanMarusyk listen, `.Annotation("Npgsql:ValueGenerationStrategy", ` is not from fluent API. It's migrations syntax, right? How do you think, is it ok to write migrations text manually? I usually don't touch migrations text, and work only via code first. I have solved my issue with the help of the following string: `migrationBuilder.RestartSequence("Languages_LanguageId_seq", 251, "public");
`. Am not sure if this approach good or not. But thanks for your help!!! PS 251 - because of I have 250 languages in the seeder.

Comment: I've just tried to help you. I didn't know about 251. Yes, you can change migrations text manually. Sometimes it is must-have. Of course if you dot write a simple app for University. "I usually don't touch migrations text, and work only via code first." - migations is a part of code first

Answer (score 0):

In the migration I have added manually this string:

```
migrationBuilder.RestartSequence("Languages_LanguageId_seq", 251, "public");
```

where `Languages_LanguageId_seq` - name of sequence, 
`251` - number of starting of the sequence (PK value),
`public` - scheme name.

Here is [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.restartsequence?view=efcore-3.1). Now I can insert without any errors.