# Data not being saved on the second loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-5

I am trying to input data using a loop. In the first loop it is able to succesfully input the data. In the second loop when it comes to saving the data it comes up with an error message

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll 
but was not handled in user code: 
'The property 'userTask.TaskScheduleId' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. 
To change the principal of an existing 
entity with an identifying foreign key, first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges', and then 
associate the dependent with the new principal.'
```

Here is the code below.
It creates a copy of the data in taskSchedule and then copies it to all the other users.
taskSchedule table has a many to many relationship with the users table which is why it is also saving data in the userTask table.

```
foreach(int user in users){
                TaskSchedule copyTaskSchedule = new TaskSchedule();
                copyTaskSchedule = taskSchedule;
                copyTaskSchedule.Id = 0;
                copyTaskSchedule.Notes = null;
                copyTaskSchedule.UserTasks = null;
                _context.TaskSchedules.Add(copyTaskSchedule);
                _context.SaveChanges();   // this is where the code stops on the 2nd loop      
            
                // add updated user to the task 
                userTask copyUserTask = new userTask();
                copyUserTask.TaskScheduleId = copyTaskSchedule.Id;
                copyUserTask.UserId = user;
                _context.userTasks.Add(copyUserTask);
                _context.SaveChanges();               
            }
```

TaskSchedule model

```
    public class TaskSchedule
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime? Start { get; set; }
        public DateTime? End { get; set; }
        public bool isClosed { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
        public byte priorityLevel { get; set; }
        public bool hasTimeLimit { get; set; }       
        public Customer customer { get; set; }
        public int? customerId { get; set; }
        public List<Note> Notes { get; set; }
        public List<AttachmentFile> Attachments { get; set; } 

        public List<userTask> UserTasks {get; set;}

        public int? userLastEditId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("userLastEditId")]
        public User userLastEdit { get; set; }
        public DateTime? userLastEditDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime taskCreatedDate { get; set; }
      
    }
```

Comment: Did you set the IDENTITY property on the table for TaskSchedule? If not and Id is the primarykey you can't insert two records with the same id

Comment: I've added the taskschedule model. Can you please explain where it's adding two records with the same id. I would have thought that creating a new object "copyTaskSchedule " would remove the old data in the 2nd loop and then create a new id when it gets inserted.

Comment: Did you try to not set it at all? If your model is correct there is no need to set that value to anything. The SaveChanges should automatically set the Id to the value assigned by the IDENTITY (autoincrement) column from the database.

Comment: Don't set that field...the database will take care of it

Comment: but I need to set the copyTaskSchedule.Id = 0; otherwise it will copy the taskSchedule id which will then clash in the database. When I create a new instance of the taskSchedule object, it automatically sets the id to 0. or is there a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

looks like  copyTaskSchedule.Id is a primary key or a foreign key . You are initializing the value to copyTaskSchedule.Id = 0;

Comment: How do I initialize it with a value that's not already been used. I'm using data from taskschedule which already has an id, then adding an id of 0 to get it to remove it. I tried adding null however it says "it is a non-nullable value type"

Comment: they "hackey" way to do it would be to read the max value of ID from DB and just keep incrementing it in the loop

Comment: Did you set it ID to auto increment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155429/auto-increment-on-partial-primary-key-with-entity-framework-core

Comment: Ok i just tried it by adding the highest value in the database but it still comes up with that error. Yes it does auto increment.

Comment: Is copyTaskSchedule.Id is a foreign key as well?

Comment: Nope, it's unique. it's the same as the TaskSchedule model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change this code

```
copyUserTask.TaskScheduleId = copyTaskSchedule.Id;
```

to this

```
copyUserTask.TaskSchedule = copyTaskSchedule;
```

Comment: I still getting the same error message. The error happens before it reaches that code so I believe there is something wrong with the code above the copyUserTask.

Comment: I read better now... i think the problem is the reference
this line... copyTaskSchedule = taskSchedule;
try to sremove this line

Comment: That works but it loses all the data such as title, start, end, isclosed, etc. Am I to assume that I need to manually enter each data one by one.

Comment: Yes you do manually... The problem is the reference with the other entity that is just marked as added...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the code below

```
copyTaskSchedule = taskSchedule;
```

Then replaced it with the following code below. I manually added each field from taskSchedule to copyTaskSchedule

```
            copyTaskSchedule.Title = taskSchedule.Title;
            copyTaskSchedule.Start = taskSchedule.Start;
            copyTaskSchedule.End = taskSchedule.End;
            copyTaskSchedule.userLastEditId = taskSchedule.userLastEditId;
            copyTaskSchedule.priorityLevel = taskSchedule.priorityLevel;
            copyTaskSchedule.isClosed = taskSchedule.isClosed;
            copyTaskSchedule.hasTimeLimit = taskSchedule.hasTimeLimit;
            copyTaskSchedule.Attachments = taskSchedule.Attachments;
            copyTaskSchedule.customerId = taskSchedule.customerId;
            copyTaskSchedule.userLastEditDate = NowDateTime;
            copyTaskSchedule.isDeleted = taskSchedule.isDeleted;
            copyTaskSchedule.taskCreatedDate = NowDateTime;
```